# ggplot2 geom_point three variables to plot x = number ocurrences y = sum of each category and colors for nationalities - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a `geom_point` with `ggplot2` to represent y = sum of amount ($) per nationality, x = number of times per nationality and colors to differentiate nationalities.

I grouped top 20 nationalities using this:

```
DF$groupnat <- fct_lump(DF$customer_country, 20)
```

With that I could group top 20 countries and the rest will be group in the value `others`

I know how to do individually but when I try to summarize all in one graph something fail. I'm not able to sum amount per nationality and same with numbers of times.

Here is an example of the Data set I'm using:

[dataframe -> DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlAFH.png)

The idea is to plot a geom_point graph involving 3 variables: x = number of observations per nationality (make a count for each nationality of the variable groupnat), y= total amount (sum of amount per nationality (groupnat)) and differentiate each nationality with a different color.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If i got you right you could use dplyr to built your dataframe and directly pipe it to ggplot. something like this maybe? df %>% group_by(groupnat) %>%  summarise(count = n(), amount = sum(desired_variable)) %>%  ggplot(.,aes(x = count, y = amount, color = groupnat)) + geom_point()

Comment: It's working for count, but for amount is calculating the total amount (sum of all values of the variable amount). What I need it's the sum of the amount per value of groupnat(US: 14000$, GB: 1250$, others: 35000$, etc.). I think that the answer It's close but I don't know exactly how to sum($amount) for the different values of groupnat. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Finally is working, my mistake, thank you so much!

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it worked :)